# Simple jQuery snippet not working in IE

Tags: jquery, dom, getelementsbytagname

Instead of using jQuery all the time, I instead built a `String` and then tried to parse it to jQuery. However, on IE I got a weird error message for the following snippet. It works fine on Chrome.

```
$('<tr><td>a</td></tr>');
```

Using just this results in the following error message on IE:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method 'getElementsByTagName'
```

What's going on here? In Chrome, like I said, it works blissfully and just as I would expect, but IE refuses to understand it.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Even this fails, is it just me having this problem?

```
$('<td>a</td>');
```

Comment: What jQuery version you are using?

Comment: @Māris Kiseļovs: I'm using version 1.5.

Comment: @alliswell: Doesn't that *select* `<tr>` and `<td>` elements? I actually want to *create* one.

Comment: ohh, my bad..anyway just for your reference i found few links [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/add-table-row-using-jquery-and.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/jquery-add-table-row).

Comment: What version of IE? also: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery2

Comment: @alliswell: Your second link solved my problem - many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start with a `<table>` and `.append('<tr>...</tr>')` to it, or if it's still empty, use `.html('<tr>...</tr>')` to fill it.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 and under are very particular about TD and TR elements.  I do not believe you can create a document fragment (which is what you are doing) containing these types of elements without a parent table element.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps IE is looking for a top level `<table> ... </table>` to surround the tr and td?